# Get no result for reading from thread in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I trying to save entry in mongodb and get id. Then I want to find this entry in thread. But sometimes I can't do it.

```
import pymongo
import bson
import threading

connection = pymongo.Connection("localhost", 27017)
db = connection.test

def set_cache(db):
    cache_id = db.test_collection.save({'test': 'some string'})
    return cache_id

def get_cache(db, cache_id):
    entry = db.test_collection.find_one({'_id' : bson.objectid.ObjectId(cache_id)})
    if not entry:
        print('No entry for %s' % cache_id)

    return entry

i = 0
while 1:
    i += 1
    cache_id = set_cache(db)

    t = threading.Thread(target=get_cache, args=(db, cache_id))
    t.start()
    t.join()

    if i > 10000:
        break
```

So, somethimes I see 'No entry for ...'. But I can see this entry in mongo. 
python2.6 
mongo 2.0.6

Comment: I find question. Use save option w=1 http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that you are using unacknowledged writes with the default usage of `pymongo.Connection` . By using this you can get into situations that the writes are not confirmed in memory but you receive the confirmation in the client. If you are faster processing the response and emitting the find request you will get into situations like this one. You are basically being too fast :)

Now if you use an acknowledge [write concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) w:1 or by just using using the new `pymongo.MongoClient` class (which I encourage you to do so) you won't get into that situation:

```
import pymongo
import bson
import threading

connection = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = connection.test

def set_cache(db):
    cache_id = db.test_collection.save({'test': 'some string'})
    return cache_id

def get_cache(db, cache_id):
    entry = db.test_collection.find_one({'_id' : bson.objectid.ObjectId(cache_id)})
    if not entry:
        print('No entry for %s' % cache_id)

    return entry

i = 0
while 1:
    i += 1
    cache_id = set_cache(db)

    t = threading.Thread(target=get_cache, args=(db, cache_id))
    t.start()
    t.join()

    if i > 10000:
        break
```

N.